# Get current view of ViewFlipper while it is flipping

Tags: android, viewflipper, android-videoview

There is any way to know want view is displayed on `ViewFlipper` while it is flipping? I have this problem : my `ViewFlipper` contains some images and one video. I want that when viewflipper display the `Videoview` with video, `ViewFlipper` to stop flipping and Video to start playing. This works only when video is displayed first time. After that, video is displayed as an image and I don't know how to catch the moment when video is displayed. Can anyone help me, pleasee?

Here is how I populate ViewFlipper :

```
private void populate() {
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println("lungime " + jArray.length());
            LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
            l.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            l.setBackgroundColor(0x000000);
            l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            vf.addView(l);

            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Images" + "/");

            File[] files = f.listFiles();

            if (files[i].getName().equals("Video" + idPhotos[i])) {
                System.out.println("Video to Viewflipper");
                System.out.println("Video Path " + files[i].getPath());
                myVideoView = new VideoView(this);
                myVideoView.setVideoPath(files[i].getPath());
                myVideoView.requestFocus();
                myVideoView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                l.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                myVideoView.setKeepScreenOn(true);

                myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        vf.stopFlipping();
                    }

                });
                myVideoView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                            downXValue = event.getX();
                            break;
                        }

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                            currentX = event.getX();
                            if (downXValue == currentX) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                                        FinActivity.class);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }

                });

                myVideoView
                        .setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                vf.startFlipping();
                            }
                        });

                vf.stopFlipping();
                myVideoView.start();
                myVideoView.setId(i);
                l.addView(myVideoView);
                l.setId(i);
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 3;
            options.inPurgeable = true;

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files[i].getPath());
            img = new ImageView(this);
            img.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            img.setOnTouchListener(this);
            l.addView(img);
            l.setId(i);
            img = null;
        }
    }
```

and on onCreate() method I have this :

```
if (ff.exists() && (files.length == jArray.length())) {     
                populate();
                vf.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        getBaseContext(), R.anim.push_left_out));
                vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        getBaseContext(), R.anim.push_left_in));
                vf.startFlipping();
}
```

(I call populate() method only once a time, maybe this is the problem)

Any idea is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Im not sure if this will work but it is worth a try.

Add an animation listener to the animation object you set as the viewflipper's 'IN' animation.
Overide the listeners onAnimationEnd method, and inside that method check

```
vf.getDisplayedChild();
```

The above code will give index of the currently displayed child. So if its in the videoview, you can stop flipping and play the video.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a [`ViewFlipper.getCurrentView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#getCurrentView()) method that directly returns the current view.